# Kind and color of orchid

Tags: orchids

I couldn't find a photo similar to my orchid. What kind and color is it?
[image: Orchid1]
[image: Orchid2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Phalaenopsis orchid, commonly known as moth orchid, and they come in a very wide range of colours - I'd describe yours as pale yellow. This is one of the easiest orchids to care for, and they make long lived houseplants, given the right conditions. They do not like to dry out, but equally must not be overwatered, never being left sitting in water in an outer tray or pot.

They like good light - a windowsill is a good situation, provided there is no radiator or other heat source directly beneath it. Further care information here https://www.repotme.com/orchid-care/Phalaenopsis-Care.html